# On-demand custom search with Pentadactyl

Tags: firefox, api, pentadactyl

I'm a Perl developer, so I often visit CPAN. I'd be happy if I could make my Pentadactyl understand command like

```
:cp List Util
```

to search CPAN for modules containing theese strings in its names. I already have CPAN search engine installed as Firefox addon, the only thing I need is the Pentadactyl API reference which I could not find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the CPAN search engine, you should be able to do this simply with the `:open` command.

e.g.

```
:open cpan list util
```

You may need to define a search keyword for the CPAN search engine first, which you can do via

```
:dialog searchengines
```